# Is there a nicer way to populate object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making a movie ticket reservation project and I am drawing a 5x5 css grid (all the "taken:true" seats turns into red). 
I need the theatre object immediately (in ngOnInit) to be filled with singleSeat objects with "taken:false" status.
This solution looks quite ugly to me, is there a better practice to achive the same result?

```js
    public theatre: IMovieTheatre[] = [];
    
const singleSeat: ISeat = {id: null, taken: false};
const row1: ISeat[] = [];
const row2: ISeat[] = [];
const row3: ISeat[] = [];
const row4: ISeat[] = [];
const row5: ISeat[] = [];
row1.push(singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat);
row2.push(singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat);
row3.push(singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat);
row4.push(singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat);
row5.push(singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat, singleSeat);
this.theatre.push({Row1: row1, Row2: row2, Row3: row3, Row4: row4, Row5: row5});
```

`

Comment: What are the definitions of `ISeat` and `IMovieTheatre`?

Comment: Do you really intend for there to be a single `ISeat` object?  If so, then `row5[2].taken = true` causes the theater to become full.  Is that the intent?

Comment: ISeat {
  id: number;
  taken: boolean;
}
and

IMovieTheatre {
  Row1?: ISeat[];
  Row2?: ISeat[];
  Row3?: ISeat[];
  Row4?: ISeat[];
  Row5?: ISeat[];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is something like this:

```
    this.theatre.push(
        (["Row1", "Row2", "Row3", "Row4", "Row5"] as const).reduce<IMovieTheatre>(
            (t, k) => (t[k] = Array.from(
                { length: 5 }, () => ({ id: null, taken: false })), t),
            {}
        ));
```

I'm assuming that you have an actual need for an `IMovieTheatre` to have keys named `"Row1"` through `"Row5"` instead of using an array.  I'm also assuming that you want each seat to be a different object, so that if you set `taken` to `true` for one of them it doesn't affect all of them.

Anyway, I'm using an array of `IMovieTheatre` key names and generating the rows and seats by [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)'s mapping function argument. It's programmatic, and somewhat idiomatic, although it could be confusing if you're not familiar with these functional array methods.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUJzMg3gWAChkTlgATALmQGcwpQBzZAH2RAFcAbLgGiNLIwcANYQQ1AEYB7aVywgiAXyJFQkWIhSoAstIBuwCABUAFlnooCxUgCVpAdwCMAfmoYLAbQC6-GyXsHACY3NExsHz9BQIBmUI8I3wE7RwAWePCwSOSAxwBWDK9vZVVCBC44GhpkMyY8HOQABw5JLmAEIXNsKAh3PUMTLssfZABeZB8AblLBHvIOEHI4cAB1CGAoch0IMFNpcgAKAEp6-0FkBGkQOlomeUz3TLG8Mip2bj4hUXFqeC4aFBKaZnQSXa44KCOJyPIrPKYNUFXG6Q4IwxJw7zA86kMHIxwxNFZbwYrHYi5IiFpQkjcbwkE4inIFF5anE2mYhGkFFOAB0zRopgONDuEEyvFuIEY9ws4uFkul2FlIrFEqloosR1J2JRQT5HAFQuVMtVCrASvl6sVJstZutmU1nJIKJieoNcrVKvdpvNHuNXptPtNDvpTrSrsF-s9Rqtkb90dtsewwbJTPy4cNFqjmbj2Zj8cDNuTZN2wBoPN2Fh66dwyEC0NTznFgSC1B1Tfxrfx7YcqU7Pe7LIbeWQSmDjqHniC3nL3xAz3oHAgk2QAHoV+xHMg4DxaBZqnAel8xCAAIQn8e4uQQHlcaSMA46zypafCY+a1frhcQc+EBpKZAzKQkg7Bo2y7PsxynCmJZlhW3TXvygrjoIByeAARHWaHihhjhBFhyA4Q4MT4YRqQkYEeRocSlTkuCRw8nMHBIAAPLoBhGGYlYQAAfAcyFkgctoiCcozccggmeCIbLIAAglAUBwAAnjyMCQgAtnxIYpucNbyJKuzUMOSjipBoniTWFDUJwPDiq+PzIH8AIjkcRy2a5-HYrgKhaYILlaiOpTebiOA4OMIAQA4NSmEwxzAmAPLAWAoE7HshzBpe8g3neBwAFLoAA8gAcjydAMJKwAwIpgnlkMPR+aUQA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you should prepopulate anything, just to have a property that says `false`. It's much easier to check if something exists at all. If you really want to have an array with all rows and seats, you can use something like below

```js
function createTheater(rows, seatsPerRow) {
  return Array.from({length: rows}, () => new Array(seatsPerRow));
}


console.log(createTheater(5, 5));
```

If the rows should allow a variable number of seats, pass an array of rows, with their respective number of seats

```js
function createTheater(rows = []) {
  return Array.from({length: rows.length}, (_, i) => new Array(rows[i]));
}

console.log(createTheater([3, 2, 4]));
```

Should you really want to prepopulate:

```js
function createTheater(rows = []) {
 return Array.from({length: rows.length}, (_, i) => Array.from({length: rows[i]}, () => ({id: null, taken: false})));
}

console.log(createTheater([3,2,1]));
```

Your object, using consecutive numbered keys, is usually replaced by an array, like shown in above result.

---

You can then assign and check seats:

```js
function createTheater(rows = []) {
 return Array.from({length: rows.length}, (_, i) => Array.from({length: rows[i]}, () => ({id: null, taken: false})));
}


function paint(t) {
  t.forEach((x, i) => {
    x.forEach((s, ii) => {
      const el = document.createElement('div');
      el.className = 'seat not-taken';
      el.style.gridRow = (i + 1) + '/' + (i + 1);
      el.setAttribute('row', i);
      el.setAttribute('col', ii);
      el.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
      document.getElementById('theater').appendChild(el);
    });
  });
}


const theater = createTheater([3,3,3,4,4,4]);
paint(theater);

function handleClick(event) {
  const {target: element} = event;
  const [row, column] = [element.getAttribute('row'), element.getAttribute('col')];
  element.classList.toggle('not-taken');
  element.classList.toggle('taken');
  
  theater[row][column] = {id: element.classList.contains('taken') ? Math.random() : null, taken: element.classList.contains('taken')}
  console.log(theater[row]);
}
```

```css
.seat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  
}

.not-taken {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.taken {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

#theater {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="theater"></div>
```